# Fourth Button in Elven Warrior's Tomb, Lower Level 2

Tags: strahds-posession

I'm playing through **Ravenloft: Strahd's Possession** (1994) and I'm currently in the **Elven Warrior's Tomb, Lower Level 2**. There is a sequence of seven doors that are opened by seven buttons scattered across the level.

The [cluebook](http://www.mocagh.org/ssi/ravenloft-cluebook.pdf) (PDF) marks the location of buttons 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 and 7, but they seem to have forgotten to mark button B4 on the map.

Does anyone know where the fourth button is?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is located at the location marked as I7 on the cluebook's map. I managed to spot it thanks to GameHorder's playthrough - if you pause [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLGw8PBWX5Y) at 0:41, you can see it marked on his automap.